# How do you to create a RegEx to match a word only if another word appears before it in the sentence?

Tags: javascript, regex, eclipse, aptana

I need to create a RegEx (that works in Eclipse's search/replace) that will match a group of letters only if a different match occurs anywhere prior in the same sentence.

Specifically, I need to match **.css** only if it occurs in the same line that includes **jsSrc**.

Eclipse doesn't support indefinite lookbehinds.

Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<% { out.print( jsSrc( request, "/builder/builder.css" />
```

Attempted regEx:

```
\.css(?<=jsSrc)
```

Does not produce a match of **.css**

Comment: do you want to return `.css` or `/builder/builder.css`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the lookbehind `?<=` the wrong way, here is the sample from book `Mastering Regular Expression`: provide you have string `see Jeffs book`, and you replace `(?<=\b Jeff)(?=s\b)` with `'`, you will get `see Jeff's book`

In your case, there's no need to use lookbehind:

```
jsSrc.*\.css
```

works for me.
Maybe you want replace only `.css` part with `XXX`, then you can do it like this:
In `Find:` field, input `(jsSrc.*)\.css` and in `Replace with:` field , input `\1XXX`

Comment: There is no need to use lookahead match, so i updated my answer!

Comment: Perfect! I needed to replace the .css part with XXX and this worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You could go with a really straight-to-the-point regex:

```
jsSrc.*\.css
```

This will match any line that contains `jsSrc` before `.css` with text inbetween both.

Though not specified in the question, if you want to match the file-path within the quotes in the line, you could use something like:

```
jsSrc.*"([^"]*\.css)"
```